# For functions of an RV, why doesn’t equating PDFs work?

Tags: statistics, random-variables

Let $ X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2) $ and $Z = \frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$. Suppose I want to prove $f_Z(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp(-\frac{1}{2}x^2)$. I tried reasoning:

$$
f_Z(x) = P(Z=x) = P(\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma} = x) = P(X = \sigma x + \mu) = f_X(\sigma x + \mu) \\
= \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}} \frac1{\sigma} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{ (\sigma x + \mu) - \mu  }{\sigma}\right)^2 \right) = \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}} \frac1{\sigma} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2} x^2 \right)
$$

However, note the pesky $\frac1\sigma$ that still remains in the above expression. That shouldn’t be there. Why is this happening? Is it invalid to equate the PDFs as I did?

**Edit:** From the comments, I realized my blooper: $f_Z(x)$ is not in fact the same as $P(Z=x)$, because of course the latter is always zero for continuous variables like $X$ and $Z$!

My revised question would be: Is there any way to understand the distribution of a function of an RV without going through the CDF, some method that works using PDFs?

Comment: You are using arguments valid only for discrete RV's to continuous RV's. Here $P(X=x)=0$ for all $x$ and $P(Z=z)=0$ for all $z$.

Comment: $P(Z=x)=0$, not $F_Z(x)$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Yes, what a brain blooper! I hope putting up this question might help someone equally dumbstruck in the future.

Comment: You want to use a combination of (a) if $Y=X+a$ then $f_Y(y)=f_X(y-a)$ and (b) if $W=bX$ then $f_W(w)=\frac1{|b|}f_X(w/b)$.  While the first of these is in a sense obvious, the second needs an argument something like the CDF, or the integral of the density being $1$, or the use of the Jacobian